# MySQL import sqldump on success rollback on failure

Tags: transactions, mysql

I have several SQL scripts (alter table, create table, insert data, update etc.).

I wrapped it into a transaction

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
//code create, alter, insert...
COMMIT
```

I thought it will process the code only on success. But I have modified tables even on failure. So I have to recover database to run script again.

I tried substitute `COMMIT` for `ROLLBACK`. But it didn't help.

Is there a way to get changes only on success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that is it impossible.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html

Answer (score 1):

try to handle errors to rollback  in case of failure :

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
    BEGIN 
        SET @error = 1;
        SET @error_string = 'erreur de type NOT FOUND';
    END;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION   
    BEGIN 
        SET @error = 1;
        SET @error_string = 'erreur de type SQLEXCEPTION';
    END;
SET @error = 0;
SET @error_string = '';
-- start transact
START TRANSACTION;
//code ...
    IF (@error <> 0) THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    //LEAVE MAj_DOC;
ELSE 
    commit;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: It will do the same. I tried to use only rollback but it did not help.

Comment: Indeed DDL statements can not be processed with a rollback,